# how to insert different table id in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

I have to table classroom and status. I want to insert classroom id in status table. My controller:

```
 $userStatus = new Status();
 $userStatus -> status_text = $text;
 $userStatus -> video_url = $request['video_url'];
 $userStatus -> type = 2;
 $userStatus -> users_id = Auth::user()->id;
 $userStatus -> save();
 Flash::success('Your status has been posted');
 return redirect(route('class'));
```

If i want to insert class id what should to do?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Where do you want to insert classroom ID? I don't see a field for that on Status table from your controller. And if you want the status to be tied to a classroom, you can rather add a status_id field to classroom table as a foreign key  referencing ID on status table.

Comment: I have a another table that classroom. It has data thats are id, class_name, section. In this case i want to insert class id in my ststus table. Becouse of user can post status specifiq class. Then how can i insert class id in my status table.

Comment: Add a `class_id` field to status table, should be a foreign key that references ID from classroom table. Then you can ```$userStatus->class_id = $value```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where class id come from ?

Otherwise you can add this line :

```
 $userStatus -> class_id = 2;
```

Comment: I have a another table that classroom. It has data thats are id, class_name, section. In this case i want to insert class id in my ststus table. Becouse of user can post status specifiq class. Then how can i insert class id in my status table.

Comment: How you get the classroom id ? There is a link between user table & classroom table ? A column ?

Comment: No there is no link.. how could i do that?

Comment: How you want to set a class room id if there isn't this ? Where come from the id ?

Comment: I already insert class data in classroom table with id (auto increment). and i also view the class name in my blade page. and also create a link on class name by id. Now my class name is more than one.So in the  class i want to post a status. thats why i want to post class id in status table. Coz when i view status it shoud be view the class by class id. coz i have more unique class.

Comment: Hi, you can use Relationships (https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships) to create a relation between the user & the classroom (by the classroom name) and so get the classroom id.